# Space between items in the legend

Tags: r, legend

I am creating a legend without a plot, but part of the items are left out, how can I avoid stuff kept out?
A possible way would be to reduce the space between the items. That's what I have done

```
plot(1, type="n", axes=FALSE, xlab="", ylab="") 
legend("bottomleft", bty = "n",inset = c(-0.2, 0),
       legend = c("AA","ABC","DEF","GHI","LMO","AAABBB","ABC ABCDEF"), 
       col=c(AA = "#8b5a00", ABC = "#5d8f21",  DEF =  "#9f69ee", 
             GHI = "#ec4e01", LMO = "#b9c000", AAABBB = "#12a0a5", "ABCDEF" = "tan1"), 
       pch=16,  cex=1, xjust=0.5, yjust=0.5, horiz=T, xpd = TRUE, x.intersp=0.5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plot window needs to be sufficiently large, you can just call it directly in `pdf()` or `png()` with enough width:

```
png("test.png", width=1000)
plot.new()
# Your legend
dev.off()
```

Comment: But this does not solve the extra space between the legend items

Answer (score 0):

I have found that text.width can control width legend text horizontally (x coordinates), first value refers to the position of the first item.

`legend("bottomleft", text.width=c(0,0.046,0.052,0.056,0.056,0.059,0.069)`...